# Access Azure AD resources without app

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

Can I access Azure AD resources, like the name of the apps and other details without registering a new app? I would like to query the REST APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The only `REST API` for Azure AD is the `Graph API`. And you have to register an app to use. The [Azure AD PowerShell Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) itself has a registered application.
You simply cannot get a token without registering an application. Azure Portal itself is also a registered application.

In the OAuth World ([explained here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2)) you have the very important part - **client**, which is the registered application in question. You cannot avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the azure-graphrbac Python package:

https://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphrbac.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure.graphrbac.graphrbacmanagementclient

This is a RestAPI official wrapper in Python, I thought it was an accurate answer to your question since you tagged "python".

Comment: If you correctly follow the links, the very important part of creating the credentials instance and obtaining the JWT token involves the use of `client` or `client_id`. You cannot simply get an OAuth Access Token without having a `client`.

Comment: i.e.: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-python - you have `client` and `key`